# Flexible center-positioned layouts with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, user-interface

I'd like to center a container `<div>` tag on a page so that it satisfies the following conditions:

1. When the screen width is greater than the `<div>`'s max width, I'd like the `<div>` to be horizontally centered within the screen.
2. When the screen width is equal to the `<div>`'s max width, the `<div>` should fill the entire screen.
3. When the screen width is smaller than the `<div>`'s max width, the `<div>` should resize to match the width of the screen.

Is this possible with CSS only, or will I need to use JavaScript to accomplish this kind of flexibility?

Comment: 1. eg you want to have scroll bar or not ? if not, why do you need this ? if yes - only javascript

Comment: I think for #1 & #2 it is possible with only CSS. Just use your max-width. Is the screen bigger, the div take the max-widht. Have the screen the same width, it will take the full screen. For #3, try to set max-width:*your width*, width:auto; I can't try it, but it's my first try...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this possible with CSS only, or will I need to use JavaScript to accomplish this kind of flexibility?

It's very possible.

### How?

The key here is the CSS [`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/max-width) property, as well as `margin: 0 auto;` for centering.

Here's a rather-well-commented jsFiddle: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/eGXrU/).

**HTML:**

```
<div class = "inner">

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.inner {
    margin: 0 auto; /*makes sure the div is centered*/
    max-width: 300px; /*maximum width*/
    width: 100%; /*default*/
    height: 100px; /*just for clarity*/
    background: dodgerblue; /*prettiness*/
}
```

As **@Cerbrus** mentioned in comments, `margin: 0 auto;` actually sets `margin-top` as well. So if you're willing to have a different value for `margin-top`, use the following instead:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Comment: Why `margin: 0 auto;`? If someone less experienced were to copy-paste the code, it might mess up their top margins.

Answer (score 0):

This will make your div with `id='myDiv'` stretch to 100% width on screens below 600px, otherwise, it will be centered.

```
#myDiv{
    width:600px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width 600px) {
    #myDiv{
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Again, I really think media queries are an overkill.

Comment: Considering that setting a width to 100% is probably not the only thing you'd want to do when implementing width-specific CSS, I disagree.
I mean, if someone's going to care about smaller screens, they will probably want to style more content differently, for compatibility reasons. In that case, media queries are pretty much the only non-js solution, and you'd need only one.

Comment: Well basically you're saying that media queries are better because you're **guessing** that the OP might need them? Well, okay. But the OP didn't mention anything about mobile-specific styling.

Answer (score 0):

See this example-

```
<div id="container"></div>​
```

CSS-

```
#container
{
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   height:500px;
   max-width:400px;
   background-color:yellow;
   min-width:100px;  //ensures that your div will resize to match the width of the screen
}​
```

See the working demo here- http://jsfiddle.net/UgxZe/4/

You can observe all the 3 scenarios you need.